# Dynamic components doesn't work in script setup

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3

I am trying to develop tabs using Dynamic component in Vue 3.2, but components are not showing up. If I change `<component :is=currentTab ></component>` to `<A/>`, it shows up, so I think `<component></component>` is not working properly, but I don't know why. If you could give me some advice I would appreciate it. Thank you.

```js
<template>
  <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="header" >
      <div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
        <button
          v-for="tab in tabs"
          v-bind:key="tab"
          v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
          v-on:click="currentTab = tab"
        >
          {{ tab }}
        </button>
        <component :is=currentTab ></component>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<template>
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import Shop from './A/A.vue';
import Knowledge from './B/B.vue';
import Community from './C/C.vue';
import router from '../../router';

const currentTab= ref('A');
const tabs =  ['A', 'B', 'C']

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it does not work. Your components are not registered by name. How could Vue know that `"A"` should be `Shop` component?

You have 2 options:

1. register components globally ([app.component()](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#global-registration)) or [locally](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration)  (not possible with `script setup` - normal `script` must be used alongside the `script setup`). Now you can pass their name as `String` into `is` and Vue will know what to do
2. **Or** pass a component object into `:is` instead of string

```js
<template>
  <div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
    <button
      v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
      v-bind:key="tab.name"
      v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab.name === tab.name }]"
      v-on:click="currentTab = tabs[i]"
    >
      {{ tab.name }}
    </button>
    <component :is="currentTab.comp"></component>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { shallowRef } from 'vue'
import Shop from './A.vue';
import Knowledge from './B.vue';
const tabs = [
  { name: 'A', comp: Shop }, 
  { name: 'B', comp: Knowledge }
]

// using shallowRef to stop Vue from turning component definitions to reactive objects
// use normal ref to see a warning
const currentTab = shallowRef(tabs[0]);
</script>
```

[Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

*If I change `<component :is=currentTab ></component>` to `<A/>`, it shows up*

Well I really doubt it - unless, of course, you have your components registered globally somewhere else (in code not shown in the question). If you try to add `<A/>` into a `<template>` in the linked demo, it does not work...

Comment: This is best answer that i'm looking for. Spent few days founding solution why composit API not work with dynamic component. +500 point to this man!

Comment: @Michal Levý
I face the same problem now and it's solved following your advice here. But something I still don't quite understand is the use of shallowRef. In my app, I put the component inside the shallowRef and it worked  but it failed when I swap shallowRef out for ref. Do you know why?

Comment: @JohnHuang If you put object into `ref`, it turns that object into reactive proxy. Component definition is an object and naturally it can be converted into reactive object. But it is unnecessary performance overhead. Reactivity has it's performance price

Comment: @Michal Levý
Thanks for the response. To the best of my understanding, `ref` and `shallowRef` should have both worked in this case. It's just that `ref` causes unnecessary performance overhead. However, `ref` didn't quite work as expected and I wonder why.